# Webstorm doesn't recognize next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, next.js, ide

I'm creating a next JS app using this command

```
npx create-next-app my-app --use-npm
```

And everything is installed successfully, but in WebStorm for example when I want to use `<Link>` from next JS it will not auto import it, so I have to import it manually and the other problem is it will not suggest any props auto-completion for next JS component.
I have no problems in react with any library.

I'll attach two images for more information.

[WebStorm not suggesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0itw.png)

[I can view this file if I click to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp2NA.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a hard struggle, eventually, I couldn't find a way to fix my problem.

So I started to use vs code, but then I realized that the WebStorm, even without its suggestions, is better than vs code .

The problem is fixed in the latest version, although if you do not want to update your WebStorm, you can use typescript.